# How do we get proper display of Hindi Unicode font on PDF Export Report from jasper Report

Tags: java, pdf, unicode

I am trying to generate pdf report from .jasper file into my web based java application with struts framework. But the font dispalyed during the pdf Report is not displayed properly([Here is the print Screen](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/files/PDF%20Report%20Preview.png)) while at the time of preview it works properly or we can export the same report in other formats like docx, html it works properly([Here is the print screen](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/files/Original%20Font%20Preview.png))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but have you tried setting isPdfEmbedded=true so that the font is included with your PDF file?

- Make the file as UTF-8
- also do the following:
  pdfFontName="YourCustomFont.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" and isPdfEmbedded="true".

example:

```
<font fontName="Mangal" size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Mangal.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download jasperreports-fonts.jar file
2. Add Mangal Font inside the jar file to the below mentioned location

> jasperreports-fonts-with-Mangal.jar\net\sf\jasperreports\fonts\dejavu

3. Make following changes in fonts.xml with inside the jar and save the file

> net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/mangal.ttf
>             net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/mangalb.ttf
>             Identity-H
>             true

4.) In jasper reports select font mangal in the above font bar.

:) Enjoy.